# jQuery on Android: focus() makes keyboard appear & disappear

Tags: android, jquery

I am using jQuery to set the focus on fields to reduce the necessary amount of clicks. This works great on desktop browsers (including Chrome) as well as on iOS. But an Android, the keyboard briefly appears and disappears automatically just milliseconds later. The keyboard appears when I manually click on the field, but does not modify the actual value once I type.

I tested both:

```
$('#discount').focus().select(); //respective
$('#discount').focus();
```

**Question**: how do I make the keyboard appear permanently & actually edit the values?

Comment: I believe it is because of a generic javascript method that acts on `$(window).resize` interrupts my focus set - I am looking into it

Comment: George, you were right. If you have resize event which alters the layout, android looses the focus on the input and thus hides the keyboard.